# Haproxy total time increases

Tags: nginx, haproxy, fastcgi

I have deployed haproxy as layer 7 loadblancer for ssl and 5 backend app sevrers running nginx on with fast-cgi cache enabled.
This is the stats page looks like. I am bit confuse about the latency shown in the yellow box. Could anyone explain it?[image]

My backend nginx log says almost 98% of the request has been served within 0.005 sec then why the total time in the HA stats page is so high.

During the load my backend server shows no trace of error but the total time in HA stats went upto 120000. 
Do I need to fine tune anything in our bakcend to get better performance or I am not reading the stats correctly.

Comment: HAProxy logs a number of timers for each request, and you should be examining these -- correlated with those from nginx -- rather than speculating from stats.  What version of HAProxy are you running? (`haproxy -v`)

Comment: I am on 1.8.3, I have read the documentation properly and it seems like any value of Tt equal to keep-alive could be the possible timeout for user is this correct?